# Cqlsh describe is missing a column visible in system.schema_columns

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3, cqlsh

After playing with Cassandra (many `DROP KEYSPACE`, `CREATE KEYSPACE`, `ALTER TABLE`, `CREATE TABLE` operations), for the second time I've ended up with following strange situation:

Describe x.logs:
[image: Describe x.logs]

System.schema_columns:
[image: System.schema_columns]

Alter table:
[image: Alter table]

`Nodetool repair` doesn't fix it. After dropping the keyspace everything goes back to normal.

My configuration:

- 1 Cassandra node cluster
- cqlsh 5.0.1
- Cassandra 2.2.0
- CQL spec 3.3.0 | Native protocol v4

**Questions**:

- What happened?
- Why that happened? Is it dangerous?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: If you have reproduction steps for how you got to this state, we would appreciate seeing them.

Comment: Unfortunately, this happened to me second time and I haven't figured out the reproduction steps yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the driver metadata model (used by cqlsh) is out of sync. This is not expected since the driver refreshes schema synchronously with DDL statements.

If you stop and restart cqlsh it will DESC what's there.

Comment: Cqlsh is a normal utility, right? I should just connect again? If that's the case, it sees "old" schema even after putty restart.

Comment: By "old", do you mean the first DESC output you show above? In that case I'm even more surprised. It sounds like schema metadata might be in some unexpected state. Reproduction steps would be key here.

Comment: Yes. So am I... Do you know if it is dangerous? Maybe someday I'll figure out the reproduction steps.

Comment: Probably not dangerous, but definitely confusing.
Could you tell me what columns are displayed if you `SELECT * FROM x.user;`?

Comment: id, time, foruser, li_ip, li_l, li_n, r_e, r_ip, r_l, r_n, type - so the full set of columns. Do you know maybe what data cqlsh describe command uses?

Comment: It uses that exact data to construct a model of the table. I'm not sure how the model could be inconsistent with the table in a single-node cluster.